# Are all left exact functor right adjoint functors?

Tags: category-theory

Right adjoint functor is left exact. I am curious about the inverse statement.

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Baire?

Comment: Right adjoints preserve *all* limits, not merely finite ones.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thanks, so can all left exact functor be realized as some right adjoint functor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The functor $T:FAb\to FAb$ from finitely generated abelian groups to finitely generated abelian groups taking a group to its torsion subgroup is left exact.

Suppose there is a functor $G:FAb\to FAb$ which is a left adjoint to $T$, so that for all f.g. abelian groups $M$ and $N$ we have $\hom(GM,N)=\hom(M,TN)$. In particular taking $M=\mathbb Z$, we see that if we set $X=G\mathbb Z$, there is a natural isomorphism $TN=\hom(X,N)$.

There is no f.g. abelian group $X$ with this property.

Indeed, suppose there is such an $X$ and that $X=\mathbb Z^l\oplus F$ with $F$ a finite abelian group. If $p$ is a prime number which does not divide the order of $F$, then $\hom(X,\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)=\hom(\mathbb Z^l,\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ has $p^l$ elements, and has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$: it follows that $l=1$. Now, if $N$ is an infinite f.g. abelian group, we have now that $\hom(X,N)$ is infinite, while the torsion subgroup $TN$ is necessarily finite. This is absurd.

Comment: Thank you. It is a nice example. Could you please offer some useful way to construct an adjoint functor? Thanks again.

Comment: @user48537, an adjoint functor to what?

Comment: To a exact functor, for example: let A be commutative ring, S be a multiple set, the localization S^-1: A-module -> S^-1 A-module. Functor F: S^-1 A-module to A-module, regard A as subring of S-1 A and acts on a S^-1 A-module. Give one side. Is there another functor gives the other side? So I can proof the exactness of localization. Thank you!

Comment: You should ask a new question, as that new question is quite unrelated to the original one!